# Present() Animation stops working when I open another view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a main view controller with 2 buttons on it, both open new views using similiar code:

```
let viewControllerTwo = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainPage") as! MainStepViewController

present(viewControllerTwo, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and both have similar dismiss usage:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If I try to present controller A, both present and dismiss animations work ok. However, If I present controller B, dismiss it and present controller A, the animations stop working. I am kinda new to iOS and I just want an idea about what to do in this case.

I tried wrapping dismiss/present with Dispatcher.main.queue but no luck.

This second controller has a sub page view controller but i don't think it is related?

Comment: Could you provide gif / short video of your problem? Because from your description you doing everything correct.

Comment: Does the debugger window say anything when the view controller fails to present? When dismissing, better practice to locate the presenting view controller by: `presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`. When you present either view controller, does the debugger ever warn you about presenting on detached view controllers?

Comment: I will try to make a gif tonight about it. @bsod: there is no issue because it is working fine... just the animation stops working, not sure why